# asp cookie vs javascript cookie

Tags: asp.net, javascript, cookies

what is the difference between asp cookie and javascript cookie.
by asp cookie i mean cookie created using response.cookie
& which one is better ?

Answer (score 4):

There isn't a difference in the underlying "cookie" itself, only the approach to setting/reading it. Both are, in fact, a client-side cookie sent to and from the browser in the request/response headers.

The difference is that the cookie can be manipulated on the client in javascript (e.g. using `document.cookie`) or on the server from within ASP.NET (e.g. using `Request.Cookies` and `Response.Cookies`).

In fact, you could mix both ASP.NET and Javascript cookie manipulation on the same cookie if you really wanted to.

[BTW - I assume you were referring to ASP.NET. ALthough you only say ASP in your question text, the question is tagged as ASP.NET]

Answer (score 2):

There is one very tiny difference. This is the time - asp uses the server time and javascript uses the from the visitor's PC. So there is one performance effect, if the server time isn't correct. Example: server time is 10:00 (5 min late from real time), visitor PC is with the correct time 10:05. In this case the cookie should probably live 5 minutes less. ( I didnt't invent the argument, only the example, origin "php power programing" )

Other than that there is one significant difference in the setting of the cookie - only server-side programming language can set a httponly cookie [<sup>wikipedia</sup>](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#HttpOnly_cookie) [<sup>owasp</sup>](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly) - cookie inaccessibly by the client-side scripting ( JScrip/JavaScript etc ). Which makes it a little less vulnerable to XSS [<sup>wikipedia</sup>](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).

Theoretically better use "asp cookie".

Answer (score 1):

Cookies are controlled by two HTTP protocol headers - Cookie and Set-Cookie. Cookie header is used in HTTP requests and Set-Cookie header is used in HTTP resonses.
Response.Cookie represents Set-Cookie header while in javascript you mainly control internal collection of cookies collection which (collection) is used for Cookie header population for the following HTTP requests.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a tiny difference between the two.
in a site I manipulate cookies via asp (classic asp) set them for example for making the user know which are the items that he viewed, or to save a list of "send me more information about this" so the user while is browsing save to the cookies the items he wants to have info on.

btw, when I invoke the function to send the email i want to delete the cookie, but if I set the cookie with JavaScript AND then I make an alert of document.cookies i have something like this:

**sendme**=;
ASPESSIONID........=........;viewed=N01;lastvied=NA002;**sendme**=NA%202322...

and this is strange, also because, making any reference to that cookie later, I’ll take always the first one, it seems that JavaScript sees the asp cookies as 1 cookie, while asp can see the JavaScript one without problems... anyone has the same thing?