# how to identify a cookie is from client-side or server-side?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, cookies

how does the  browser differentiate a cookie is from client-side created (JavaScript) or server-side created (ASP.NET). Is it possible to delete cookie created from server side in client side and  vice versa, I'm struggling to delete a cookie was created from client-side using javascript in ASP.NET code-behind.

Comment: [asp cookie vs javascript cookie](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945248/asp-cookie-vs-javascript-cookie)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> how does the browser differentiate a cookie is from Client side(javascript created) or serverside created (Asp.net).

It doesn't. A cookie is a cookie.

The closest it comes is the *HTTP Only* flag, which allows a cookie to be hidden from JavaScript. (This provides a little defence against XSS cookie theft).

> it is possible to delete cookie created from server side in client side and vice versa

Yes. A cookie is a cookie. (Again, client side code can't touch an HTTP only cookie)

Comment: i solved the problem actually my client side script followed UTC time format and in serverside GMT format, while deleting i just   did " oCookie.Expires =DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d).ToUniversalTime();" still has some  doubt since you said "it is possible to delete cookie created from server side in client side and vice versa" why cant i delete a http only cookie is there any security behind that property..

Comment: There is nothing but security being the property. The whole point of it is to hide it from client side scripting.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know it is possible if there is not property **HttpOnly** [<sup>owasp</sup>](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly) [<sup>wikipedia</sup>](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#HttpOnly_cookie).

In chrome, for the cookies, there is a field - **Accessible by script**, which indicates if HttpOnly is set.

Comment: thanks spending your valuable time i gone through both links its very informative.