# Recognize HTTP cookies with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, cookies, safari

With Safari's ITP 2.1 all client-side cookies will be gone after 7 days. Only HTTP cookies (created via Set-Cookie header response) will persist.

Based on the above, it becomes important to me to be able to recognize which cookies are HTTP cookies (created via Set-Cookie header response) and which aren't.

Is there anyway to recognize the cookie type/origin via JavaScript? How does Safari differentiate HTTP cookies from client-side cookies for their deletion process?

**Note:** When I say HTTP cookies I refer to server-side cookies that were created/set via Set-Cookie header response and **do not** have the `HttpOnly` flag and also **do not** have the `secure` flag. I'm aware `HttpOnly` cookies are not accessible via JavaScript.

Comment: Any ideas? This previous Stackoverflow thread advised there is no difference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10100940/how-to-identify-a-cookie-is-from-client-side-or-server-side
But seeing Safari's ITP 2.1 there is clearly a difference and there are also ways to differentiate them in order to remove them after 7 days. But it's not clear to me how and whether they can be identified with JavaScript